# Noob confused with DNS and WHM /cPanel install

Tags: domain-name-system, vps

I just signed up with Knownhost using their VPS. I have never used the WHM before, and it is confusing me a little. From what I understand the WHM is used to manage multiple domains on a single server (vps). I only need one domain for the entire server, so I setup one user "oranges" with the domain oranges.com (ok so thats not the real domain :) .

When I purchased the VPS, I had to enter a domain and selected I would transfer later, so I entered oranages.com . 20/20 seeing how WHM works (kinda) I am wondering if they wanted a domain for the server? such as MyWebServer1.com ? Reason being if I enter my ip address in the browser, I get a generic cPanel page, not my test index.html that is uploaded with the "oranges" user.

The email from knownhost says,

> You need to create the following name 
>   servers at your registrar: 
>   ns1.oranges.com using IP 204.197.xxx.xxx 
>   ns2.oranges.com using IP 204.197.xxx.xxx

The hostname of the server (under main>DNS functions) is host.oranges.com with the first IP listed above.

namecheap.com has a section: add (register) nameservers that says ns1.oranges.com = and you can input your ip's.

Ok so after all of this, can I just register them with namecheap? and do I need to fowared anything in WHM? or did I botch up the registration? Also I am more than willing to read up on the required stuff, but I can't find anything specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact interface varies from registrar to registrar, but somewhere you will need to add two DNS Hosts.  On GoDaddy, you type in the host name of each DNS host relative you your own domain, in this case, it's ns1 and ns2, then next to it, enter the IP Address.  It will probably have .orange.com after the field where you put in the name of each DNS host representing the whole name as ns1.orange.com and ns2.orange.com.  Here is GoDaddy's help for this: http://help.godaddy.com/topic/833/article/3952?locale=en

Elsewhere on your registrar, you will need to set up the NS records to point to the aforementioned names.  You will enter in the full names here, ns1.orange.com and ns2.orange.com.  It will say something like "I have specific nameservers for my domains"  For GoDaddy, here is there help: http://help.godaddy.com/topic/833/article/664?locale=en#reghere

For other registrars you will have to figure out from their docs, but it should be similar.

Comment: penguin359 is correct. The nameservers you list need to be registered with your registrar that hosts `oranges.com`. This solves the chicken and the egg problem of being able to get to name servers before you can actually create A records for them. But you will also need to create the A records for them in the WHM.

Comment: Woooot Thanks guys =D  It works! I registered the nameservers last night, but did not update the A-record on namecheap. After reading both your posts, I updated the A-record and within 5mins it resolved to my server...fast! Also my TTL is 1800 for the A-record, is that ok?

Comment: Yes.  If you plan to move to a different IP later, you can lower the TTL, say, an hour or more before the move to improve the speed of clients seeing the new A-record once you update it.